# Opening a link in new tab PHPFOX

Tags: phpfox

I am trying to add new child menu through ***PHPFOX*** admincp which should open target URL in new tab. I've tried directly adding anchor tag with `target="_BLANK"` in language package details under `CMS=>menus=>edit menus`, but then it creates two menus one with blank label and one with anchor tag entered as below:

`{a href="http://domain.com/index.php?do=/module_name/controller" target="_blank">menu</a>}`

Comment: there are no directly option in admin to set target="_blank", if you want this you have to change code in file

Comment: It would be great if you can tell the template to edit ?

Comment: file path - module\core\template\default\block\template-menu.html.php

Comment: Thanks @AnkitAgrawal! Appreciated :)